# Can the Cronos block/unblock an account?

Tags: go-ethereum, cosmos

My wallet on the cronos is unable to send any transactions for now.
So I googled some documents and found some codes in the cosmos-sdk.

There are some keepers to block addresses. So I think, the chain can block an account if they want.

What do you think of this? Is it possible to block/unblock an account on the cronos using the cosmos-sdk? If possible, how to unblock my account?

I'd like to know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.